# Should Hibernate Session#merge do an insert when receiving an entity with an ID?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, concurrency

This seems like it would come up often, but I've Googled to no avail.

Suppose you have a Hibernate entity `User`. You have one `User` in your DB with id 1.

You have two threads running, A and B. They do the following:

- A gets user 1 and `close`s its `Session`
- B gets user 1 and `delete`s it
- A changes a field on user 1
- A gets a new `Session` and `merge`s user 1

All my testing indicates that the `merge` attempts to find user 1 in the DB (it can't, obviously), so it inserts a new user with id 2.

My expectation, on the other hand, would be that Hibernate would see that the user being merged was not new (because it has an ID). It would try to find the user in the DB, which would fail, so it would not attempt an insert or an update. Ideally it would throw some kind  of concurrency exception.

Note that I am using optimistic locking through `@Version`, and that does not help matters.

So, questions:

1. Is my observed Hibernate behaviour the intended behaviour?
2. If so, is it the same behaviour when calling `merge` on a JPA `EntityManager` instead of a Hibernate `Session`?
3. If the answer to 2. is yes, why is nobody complaining about it?

Comment: Have you tried using optimistic locking (`@Version`)? This _may_ catch inserting rows with a version set. I'm not sure about it, however.

Comment: I have, in fact. It does not affect the outcome. But yeah, you would expect that to help too.

Comment: I'm astonished by the behavior as well. Looks like a huge bug to me. Which version are you using?

Comment: Looks like a bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-972

Comment: Good catch. may b you should start using a flag 'deleted' on the user object and apply filter when fetching as a work around.

Comment: Here's a more up-to-date bug: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1661. Incredibly, this has not been fixed even though it was reported in 2005 and again in 2006!

Comment: Might be worth voting up this bug. It looks like a really serious one to me (that should have been called by the TCK)

Comment: I voted up 1661, since it seems to have gotten more attention. I also marked 972 as a duplicate. Is there anything else we can do to bring more attention to this?

Comment: I voted as well. This behavior is a serious issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking at JSR-220, from which `Session#merge` [claims to get its semantics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#merge%28java.lang.Object%29). The JSR is sadly ambiguous, I have found.

It does say:

> Optimistic locking is a technique that is used to insure that updates
>   to the database data corresponding to the state of an entity are made
>   only when no intervening transaction has updated that data since the
>   entity state was read.

If you take "updates" to include general mutation of the database data, including deletes, and not just a SQL `UPDATE`, which I do, I think you can make an argument that the observed behaviour is not compliant with optimistic locking.

Many people agree, given the comments on my question and the subsequent discovery of [this bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-1661).

From a purely practical point of view, the behaviour, compliant or not, could lead to quite a few bugs, because it is contrary to many developers' expectations. There does not seem to be an easy fix for it. In fact, Spring Data JPA seems to ignore this issue completely by blindly [using `EM#merge`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java). Maybe other JPA providers handle this differently, but with Hibernate this could cause issues.

I'm actually working around this by using `Session#update` currently. It's really ugly, and requires code to handle the case when you try to `update` an entity that is detached, and there's a managed copy of it already. But, it won't lead to spurious inserts either.

Comment: The JSR does have this in it under merge (pg51).. "If X is a removed entity instance, an IllegalArgumentException will be thrown by the
merge operation (or the transaction commit will fail)"... Which I would consider to directly contradict the hibernate behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the text from hibernate documentation below.

***Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. If the given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent instance.***

It clearly stated that copy the state(data) of object in database. if object is not there then save a copy of that data. When we say save a copy hibernate always create a record with new identifier.

Hibernate merge function works something like as follows.

1. It checks the status(attached or detached to the session) of entity and found it detached.
2. Then it tries to load the entity with identifier but not found in database.
3. As entity is not found then it treat that entity as transient.
4. Transient entity always create a new database record with new identifier.

Locking is always applied to attached entities. If entity is detached then hibernate will always load it and version value gets updated.

Locking is used to control concurrency problems. It is not the concurrency issue.

Comment: You're correct that this is not strictly a concurrency issue. However, the problem will be most often manifested in concurrent situations. I'm aware of what Hibernate is doing, the question is whether its correct or not. I think there's some ambiguity that warrants the question, especially since it can quite easily lead to bugs.

Answer (score 0):

1.Is my observed Hibernate behaviour the intended behaviour?

The behavior is correct. You just trying to do operations that are not protected against concurrent data modification :) If you have to split the operation into two sessions. Just find the object for update again and check if it is still there, throw exception if not. If there is one then lock it by using em.(class, primary key, LockModeType); or using @Version or @Entity(optimisticLock=OptimisticLockType.ALL/DIRTY/VERSION) to protect the object till the end of the transaction.

2.If so, is it the same behaviour when calling merge on a JPA EntityManager instead of a Hibernate Session?

Probably: yes

3.If the answer to 2. is yes, why is nobody complaining about it?

Because if you protect your operations using pessimistic or optimistic locking the problem will disappear:)

The problem you are trying to solve is called: Non-repeatable read

Comment: Well, no, actually. As I stated in the question, optimistic locking does not help this situation. Pessimistic locking would probably work (I've not used it), but that's a rather draconian workaround to a problem that can be easily solved otherwise.

Comment: hmm Why does the optimistic locking not help? If you find the object again then hibernate will do "update X where version = ?" instead of insert statement. It does that in my code. Am I wrong ? If the update statement can not find anything then it means the version was changed or the object disappeared and throws an OptimisticLockingException.

Comment: Check the update statement, please. If there is no where with version clause then you are doing something wrong. If you specify OptimisticLockType to All or Dirty then instead of version you will have where with all parameters or all modified parameters.

Comment: That's the thing, there is no update statement in this case (my other update statements do include the version in a where clause). Using merge in this case, Hibernate simply does a select by id (which returns nothing), followed by an insert when the session is flushed. I agree that optimistic locking _should_ solve this problem though :-).

Comment: Just to be clear Do you use find() in the scope of the next session ? That the object can be tracked by entityManager again? If dont do this then the behavior is proper. EM has to ask if the object exists and then insert/update. If you do and still it queries before the insert then it is a bug in my opinion as well.

Comment: No, find() is not used in the second session, so merge does it. IMO, when the merge does not find an existing record, it should see that the passed-in entity has an ID (and version), know that it's not a new entity, and throw an exception.

Comment: But you are wrong in assumption that Id indicates if an object is new or for update. The object is for update if it is tracked by EM or exists in the datastore. You can easily check if an object is a managed entity instance belonging to the current persistence context by using entityManager.contains(Object entity) If you don't use find  then it won't be. The result you already know. For me it is not a bug but feature :)

Comment: I think an object having an ID indicates unequivocally that it should not be inserted (same thing for version). But, I think we will have to agree to disagree on that one, your point is noted.